# First 3 maximum elements grouped by id

Tags: qgis, spatialite

A point layer with an `ele` attribute and another `id_2` attribute. What I'm trying to do is to get the **first 3 maximum** elements of `ele` for each `id_2`

With a simple SQL query I can get the maximum element (just the max!) for each `id_2`:

```
SELECT geom, max(ele), id from layerA
group by id_2
```

How can I get the other 2 maximum elements?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select geom, id
from layerA
where (
   select count(*) from layerA as layA
   where layA.id_2 = layerA.id_2 and layA.ele <= layerA.ele
) <= 3;
```

Comment: thanks for the hints.. The first solution is not what I'm looking for: it limits at 3 the whole layer, I need the 3 max **for each** group. With the second suggestion I get an error: `near "3": syntax error`

Comment: edited answer based on following: [https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I get an empty result...

Comment: what sort of data is in each attribute? Just looking at th code I posted, it won't work if "ele" is not a number.

Comment: mmm nope.. always an empty result.. I'm sure that the column is numeric (real)